# how to get process/ service information from the pid/port with Node

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, socket.io, node-modules

I have list of pids/ports (by using cmd line with NodeJS).

I want to filter only those pid/port on which only node server is running.(without using pm2)

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       844
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8488
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2701           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4432
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19908
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3100           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       23688
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12252
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3300           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18616
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1152
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5700           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       10848
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16800
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9012           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7416
  TCP    0.0.0.0:16992          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8488
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       648
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1572
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1944
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2416
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3208
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       808
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       808
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49671          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       720
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49679          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4964
  TCP    10.191.74.99:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    10.191.74.99:5040      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       440
  TCP    10.191.74.99:7680      10.191.63.231:57996    SYN_RECEIVED    10848
.......
```

Comment: What is the command you use ?

Comment: @TGrif, netstat -aon